# fetch data between dates from database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to get data from Sqlite database which has the table name "healthstatusdetails" as below:

```
DateTime            Event
2017/08/22 18:53:19 333333333
2017/08/22 19:56:13 1502979973309
2017/08/23 19:59:14 1502980154180
2017/08/23 19:59:39 1502980179349
2017/08/23 20:01:16 1502980276106
2017/08/24 10:39:28 1503378568212
2017/08/24 16:37:39 1503572859460
2017/08/25 16:39:16 1503572956376
2017/08/25 16:41:56 1503573116260
```

I've tried this query:

```
select DateTime, Event from healthstatusdetails WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '2017/08/22' AND '2017/08/24';
```

I got the follow data:

```
2017/08/22 18:53:19 333333333
2017/08/22 19:56:13 1502979973309
2017/08/23 19:59:14 1502980154180
2017/08/23 19:59:39 1502980179349
2017/08/23 20:01:16 1502980276106
```

If my code is:

```
select DateTime, Event from healthstatusdetails WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '0' AND '2017/08/24';
```

then also I am getting same output

```
2017/08/22 18:53:19 333333333
2017/08/22 19:56:13 1502979973309
2017/08/23 19:59:14 1502980154180
2017/08/23 19:59:39 1502980179349
2017/08/23 20:01:16 1502980276106
```

How do I overcome this?

I need data output including '2017/08/24' events

I need to include in the retrieved data, the events from '2017/08/24'

the selection of dates from where to where fetch the data is from the user side, it's not in our controll. if user entered dates from '0' to '2017/08/24' then it would be a big problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: `DATETIME` is literally that - a `DATE` and a `TIME`.  If you don't specify a time, it will default to `00:00:00`, which is why you aren't getting dates on the 24th, since they're *after* `2017-08-24 00:00:00`.  A way you can get your results would be: `WHERE DateTime >= '2017-08-22' AND DateTime < '2017-08-25'`.

Comment: @Siyual read the question. It's not '2017-08-22'  but  '2017/08/22'.

Comment: @Siyul You are right Thanks, half of my problem solved. but the selection of dates 'from' where 'to' where( ...BETWEEN '0' AND '2017/08/24') fetch the data are from the user side, it's not in our control. if user entered dates from '0' to '2017/08/24' then it would be a big problem. help me to overcome this.